# Can not use web-assembly rust impl because of 'Cannot access '__wbindgen_throw' before initialization' error

Tags: typescript, webpack, rust, web-component, webassembly

I am trying to add some web-assembly to my project. On the beginning I created a simple method to check is my webpack works well and can I use my `.wasm` modules. So I created somthing like this:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn return_char() -> char {
    return 'a';
}
```

And then I used this inside constructor of my web-component (just to check is everything works fine):

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
    console.log(return_char());
}
```

This worked as expected I saw `'a'` in my web-app console:

[image]

Then when I saw that everything works fine I created struct with implementation:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Test {
    value: char
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Test {
    pub fn new() -> Test {
        let value: char = 'a';
        Test {
            value
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> char {
        self.value
    }

    pub fn change_value(&mut self) {
        self.value = 'b';
    }
}
```

Then I add created instance of `Test` inside the same web-component class constructor and call methods of this `Test` impl. I thought that I should see `'a'` and `'b'` in my console

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
    const test: Test = Test.new();
    console.log(test.value());
    test.change_value();
    console.log(test.value());
}
```

But this didn't happen and I saw only this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access '__wbindgen_throw' before initialization at Module.__wbindgen_throw (calculator_engine_bg.js:5)

I do not know why I am getting this error and how can I fix this. Maybe there is a problem with my `webpack.config.js` ?

```js
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    experiments: {
        asyncWebAssembly: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

GitHub repository with minimal code needed to reproduce: [webpack-web-assembly-rust-impl-bug](https://github.com/kaczor6418/webpack-web-assembly-rust-impl-bug)

> webpack version: 5.0.0-beta.26

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? The example code you have there works fine when I try it with a `create-wasm-app` project.

Comment: @Herohtar I added [repro steps to README.md](https://github.com/kaczor6418/webpack-web-assembly-rust-impl-bug/blob/example-without-error/README.md). Did you follow this steps and you still don't  see any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as ***sokra*** mentioned in his answer under [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11347) which I created. I should use `experiments.syncWebAssembly` instead of `experiments.asyncWebAssembly`. If I use this `experiments.syncWebAssembly` I have to add additional file which will asynchronously load `index.ts` file.

***`webpack.config.js`***

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: './src/bootstrap.ts', // !! <- change path to bootstrap.ts
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    experiments: {
        syncWebAssembly: true // !! <- use syncWebAssembly instead of asyncWebAssembly
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

***`bootstrap.ts`***

```js
import('./index').catch(e => console.error('Error importing `index.js`:', e))
```

Full solution you can find here:: [webpack-web-assembly-rust-impl-bug](https://github.com/kaczor6418/webpack-web-assembly-rust-impl-bug)

Comment: `syncWebAssembly ` is deprecated now :(

Comment: @kigawas `syncWebAssembly` is not deprecated. More about this experimental feature you can find it here ***[experiments - sync WebAssembly](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/)***

Comment: This is still an issue until now. Any follow ups or fix? Setting webpack to syncWebAssembly causes another issue.

Comment: @iismaell what issue you are getting? Did you have tried the template [web-assembly-rust-typescript-template](https://github.com/kaczor6418/web-assembly-rust-typescript-template) which I have created?