# Rust Wasm - The Game Of Life tutorial has failed to compile a webpack-dev-server

Tags: rust, webassembly

```
System description:
macOS Big Sur ver. 11.4
MacBook Pro
Processor: 2.4
Mem: 8GB
Graphics: Intel Iris 1536 MB
```

Webpack-dev-server compiler 2 issues during the installation process.

1st issue.

npm run start

```
> create-wasm-app@0.1.0 start /Users/name/RUSTWASM/TUTORIAL/gameoflife/www
> webpack-dev-server

/Users/name/RUSTWASM/TUTORIAL/gameoflife/www/node_modules/schema- 
utils/dist/validate.js:105
throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
^

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using 
an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

**2nd  Issue

```
The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly 
module for webpack.
```

Answer (score 1):

1st issue

I have found a solution for that issue here.
[npm run dev fails : ValidationError: Invalid options object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937054/npm-run-dev-fails-validationerror-invalid-options-object)

It's a webpack config syntax error:

Old syntax:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  [
    { from: '', to: '' },
    { from: '', to: '' }
  ]
)
```

New syntax:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  { 
    patterns: [
      { from: '', to: '' },
      { from: '', to: '' }
    ]
  }
)
```

2nd issue

The solution for the second issue is inside this file: webpack.config.js according to [Can not use web-assembly rust impl because of 'Cannot access '__wbindgen_throw' before initialization' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494610/can-not-use-web-assembly-rust-impl-because-of-cannot-access-wbindgen-throw)

```
experiments: {
    syncWebAssembly: true // !! <- use syncWebAssembly instead of asyncWebAssembly
},
```

Full working code here.
https://github.com/cichy/gameoflife

Comment: If you haven't already, consider making a post on the repo's issue tracker. Hopefully these problems can get addressed. Or better yet, consider making a PR.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help.